# what is wrong with my reverse function

Tags: c

I'm trying to writing a function to reverse a string: If the string input is `"Hello World"`, the function should return `"dlroW olleH"`. However, when I run my function the string stays the same:

```
void reversestring(char* s) {
    char tmp;   //tmp storing the character for swaping
    int length; //the length of the given string
    int i;      //loop counter

    //reverse the string of even length
    length = strlen(s);
    if (length % 2 == 0) { //if the length of the string is even
        for(i = 0; i < (int) (length / 2);i++) {
            tmp = s[length - i];
            s[length - i] = s[i];
            s[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    //reverse the string of odd length
    if (length % 2 == 1) { //if the length of the string is odd
        for(i = 0; i < (int) ((length + 1) / 2);i++) {
            tmp = s[length + 1];
            s[length + 1] = s[i];
            s[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in main function, I call it like this: s = strdup(argv[1]); // Sring to reverse if (strcmp(basec, "reversestring") == 0) {
    printf("Original string: %s\n", s);
    reversestring(argv[1]);
    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", s);

Comment: First at all: the indexing in the second branch needs revising to s[xxx + i]; now it's accessing the string after the end mark. And if you think it carefully, you can combine those odd/even cases -- just don't swap the middle term.

Comment: `s[length - i]` if `i = 0` at the begining is also a bug.

Comment: Secondly, you are (trying) to reverse the original string, but printing the copy. Try `printf("%s",argv[1]); reverse(s); printf("%s",s);`

Comment: I think you're making your life a lot harder than it needs to be. Have you considered something [a little simpler](http://ideone.com/4SP8iN)?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop to deal with strings. And the symmetric character of `s[i]` is `s[length-i-1]`,

```
void reverse(char* s) {
  char tmp; //tmp storing the character for swaping
  int length; //the length of the given string
  int i; //loop counter

  //reverse the string of even length
  length = strlen(s);

  if (length < 2) return;

      for(i = 0; i < (int) (length / 2);i++){
          tmp = s[length - i - 1];
          s[length - i - 1] = s[i];
          s[i] = tmp;
      }
}
```

Exemple:

```
abcde
01234
```

*length* is 5, `length / 2` is `2` (integer division). *length* is odd, but you don't have to move the central character. Characters that need to be swapped

```
(0,4), (1,3)
```

Test:

```
int main () {
    char x[] = "Hello World";
    reverse(x);
    printf("%s \n",x );
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
 dlroW olleH
```

Comment: nice answer, thank you very much and thank everyone that helps me on the debugging : }

Comment: Thank you - please accept the answer if it is satisfactory enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are off by one in indexing. The symmetric of `s[0]` is not `s[length- 0]` , but `s[length-0-1]`.

As for the odd case I don't get it what exactly you try to do but it seems you easily go out of bounds on each iteration.